# In Mac/iOS programming, what is a "Foundation Object"?

Tags: ios, foundation

I've seen reference to "Foundation Object" (specifically in the NSJSONSerialization Class docs https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/foundation/reference/nsjsonserialization_class/Reference/Reference.html), however I'm not really sure what a "Foundation Object" is, and is it different than a "Core Foundation Object"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It tells you in that link bout 3 lines further down.

The objects can be instances of...

- NSArray
- NSDictionary
- NSNumber
- NSDate
- NSString
  or
- NSNull